# Navbar dropdown list auto open and auto close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I added a dropdown list to the navbar on another site and added the class .open to the list.  My intention is as follows: upon load the webpage navbar list contains an img element and opens displaying a promotional offer.  So far so good, the page loads and the list drops displaying the ad, and if clicked it then closes.

Ok what I am aiming for is adding a function via jquery or JavaScript or css which will automatically CLOSE the dropdown list after about 5 seconds.  I have read that the .open class in bootstraps.min.css is not cleared by default and therefore will remain open unless it is 'clicked' to close it.

```
 <div class="navbar-responsive">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="active">
     <li class="open dropdown-menu">
      <a href="#" Id="test" class="dropdown-toggle" data-               toggle="dropdown"><strong class="caret">
```

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li>
         <a href="#">Click to close.</a>
      </li>

           <li>
             <img src="image folder/my_ad_image.png" 
            </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
     </li>
   </ul>
     </div><!---end nav collapse--->
    </div><!---end container--->
   </div>>!---end main navbar--->
```

This above is what I have written.  It rests atop an already existing navbar.
Thanks for reading.

If anyone has any suggestion or could point me in the right direction with respect to tying a jquery timeout function to my .open class or id that would be great.  So far I have been unable to tie a jquery function or css to my dropdown list
Thanks.

Comment: A little jQuery will do the job nicely. What have you tried? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-methods

Comment: I tried opacity ease out starting with 1 moving to 0 but it does not close the dropdown.  I'm either trying wrong approaches or the class .open needs to be released.  Can't be certain

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to implement timers in javascript.

> The [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   after a specified number of milliseconds.

Adapting your code it can be implemented like this:

CSS:

```
...
<li id="myid" class="open dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong class="caret"></strong></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Click to close.</a>
        </li>

        <li> ... </li>
    </ul>
</li>
...
```

jScript (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#myid").removeClass("open")
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to use the dropdown's `hide()` method instead, just in case it does other things to the DOM.

Comment: @isherwood of course, `hide()` is more fitting here. I just wanted to show a little example out of context to emphasize on `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Thanks but isn't working.  Maybe the drop class is relaesed I don't know but the list does not close again after five seconds.  Still only closing on click.

Comment: @GreatScott I've made a jsfiddle for you to demonstrate it here: https://jsfiddle.net/75zkat4j/4/   ... be advised you've some html errors in your mockup, too - this might cause you some issues.

Comment: Thanks for this. Checked my code on this and it's correct so I suppose my jquery links are messed up?  I think having this sitting inside another navbar must be breaking linking.  At least I know this parts is right, thanks for your help'

Comment: @GreatScott Check out your browsers debugger to find out what is wrong. It usually is highlighted in the console.